# Save image Doctrine2

Tags: php, sqlite, doctrine-orm, image

Does anyone know how to save an image into my SQLite db with Doctrine2? I already got a BLOB "pic_data" and a string "pic_type", but how do i hava to go on?

Greetings,
BigTeddy

Comment: Do you really need to store the image in the DB? Can't you store it in the file system see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3751/1059001.

Comment: Well okay I'll do it like this... :D But how should the files be named?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the files are called if you store the file name in the database instead of the file itself.

Comment: But if two people upload a picture with the same name? E.g. A uploads picture "cake.jpg" and B uploads another picture named "cake.jpg".

Comment: Do you need to retain the filename or can you just append the system timestamp (see php time() function) to the filename? Like cake_1138618081.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to store the image in the DB? Can't you store it in the file system.

See [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay/3751#3751) for discussion about this.

You can just append the system timestamp (see php time() function) to the filename to make it unique.

```
$newFilename = time().'_'.$filename;

//results in 1138618081_cake.jpg
```